# Adding a new column to the pandas dataframe by merging other columns and renaming based on previous column names

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge several columns into a new one and rename the values based on those column names. I have this dataframe:

```
    P1  P2  P3  P4
1               T1
2       T4
3           T3
4   T1
5           T6
```

And want to change it to this one (adding the last column):

```
    P1  P2  P3  P4  PAll
1               T1  P4
2       T4          P2
3           T3      P3
4   T1              P1
5           T6      P3
```

I have tried + and also stacking but could not reach the final answer.

I appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Are the empty spaces just empty strings, i.e. `''`? Or are they NaN?

Comment: Is possible some row have no value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `pandas.DataFrame.eq` and `idxmax`:

```
df['PALL'] = df.eq('T1').idxmax(1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   P1  P2  P3  P4 PALL
0              T1   P4
1      T1           P2
2          T1       P3
3  T1               P1
4          T1       P3
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That solved the problem. However, what can we do if we get different values instead of single "T1" in each column? For instance, T1, T2, T3...

Comment: @mah65 That depends. Can you elaborate more, possibly by editing your question?

Comment: I edited the question to make it more comprehensive

Comment: @Chris This answer should still work, just replace `.eq('T1')` with `.notna()`.

Comment: @brentertainer Thanks for the comment :) Let me edit accordingly

Comment: @Chris  - Maybe the best add to answer when it working - cannot be empty row, because get False positive value, cannot be multiple values, because get only first...

Comment: @jezrael I agree. There can be lots of variations depending on what those _seemingly_ white spaces are composed of: they can be pure `' '`s, `NaN`s, and worse, mixture of two. I'll wait for OP's answer to your latest comment.

Comment: @Chris - Yes, I always a bit worried if answer working only in specific conditions (and OP dont know it), so the best add it to answer. but it is up to you...

Answer (score 0):

If need all values, not only first use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html):

```
df['PAll'] = df.notna().dot(df.columns + ';').str.rstrip(';')
print (df)
    P1   P2   P3   P4 PAll
1  NaN  NaN  NaN   T1   P4
2  NaN   T4  NaN  NaN   P2
3  NaN  NaN   T3  NaN   P3
4   T1  NaN  NaN  NaN   P1
5  NaN  NaN   T6  NaN   P3
```